# Equivalent definitions of differentiability for curves defined on closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ \gamma\colon [a,b[\to \mathbb R^n $ be a curve (i.e. a continuous function). Studying differential geometry I came across two ways in which $ \gamma $ can be called "differentiable".

1. $ \gamma $ is differentiable if it is differentiable in the classical sense in the interior $ ]a,b[ $ (meaning $ \gamma(t) $ always exists when $ a < t < b $), and if
   $$
   \gamma^\prime(a) := \lim_{\substack{h\to 0\\h > 0}}\frac{\gamma(a + h) - \gamma(a)}{h}
   $$
   exists (and the map $ \gamma^\prime\colon [a,b[\to \mathbb R^n $ is again differentiable in this extended sense and so on).
2. $ \gamma $ is differentiable if for every $ t\in [a,b[ $ there is some open neighborhood $ U $ of $ t $ (with respect to the topology of $ \mathbb R $!) and a differentiable curve $ \lambda\colon U\to \mathbb R^n $ such that $ \lambda \equiv \gamma $ on $ U\cap [a,b[ $.

Are they equivalent? Of course (2) implies (1). But does the converse hold? I'm concerned in particular with the case where "differentiable" = "smooth" = "of differentiability class $ \mathscr C^\infty $".

Comment: In 2. How do you define the differentiability of $\lambda\,?$

Comment: I'm using just the classical notion of differentiability for a map defined on an open set in this case.

Comment: You also wrote differentiable in the classical sense for $\gamma$ in 1. Is it not obvious then that (2) implies (1)? If $\gamma$ is locally identical to a classically differentiable $\lambda$ then $\gamma$ is classically differentiable. Edit: I also don't see a problem with $1\Rightarrow 2\,.$ The $\lambda$ you need there is the $\gamma$ itself. Don't overthink this.

Comment: Yes $ (2)\implies (1) $ is obvious. But to show $ (1)\implies (2) $, and in particular that for $ t = a $ there is some curve $ \lambda\colon U\to \mathbb R^n $ defined on an open neighborhood of $ a $ and there (classically) differentiable I can't just take $ \lambda = \gamma $, since $ \gamma $ is not defined for $ t < a $.

Comment: I think I need to find some smooth extension of $ \gamma $ near $ a $ but I'm not well versed in analysis. My idea is the following. I do have a "velocity" vector $ \gamma^\prime(a) $ in $ a $. Then I define $ \lambda \colon ]a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon[\to \mathbb R^n $ by $ \lambda(t) = \gamma(a) + t\gamma^\prime(a) $ if $ t < a $, and $ \lambda(t) = \gamma(t) $ if $ t\geqq a $. But then I need to check that this thing $ \lambda $ is $ \mathscr C^\infty $ at $ t = a $ and I'm not sure I'm able to do it.